# Pickle breaking change in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I have custom list and dictionary classes that no longer work while unpickling in Python 3.7.

```
import pickle

class A(dict):
    pass

class MyList(list): 

    def __init__(self, iterable=None, option=A):
        self.option=option
        if iterable:
            for x in iterable:
                self.append(x)

    def append(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            obj = self.option(obj)
        super(MyList, self).append(obj)

    def extend(self, iterable): 
        for item in iterable:
            self.append(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pickle_file = 'test_pickle'
    my_list = MyList([{'a': 1}])
    pickle.dump(my_list, open(pickle_file, 'wb'))
    loaded = pickle.load(open(pickle_file, 'rb'))
    print(isinstance(loaded[0], A))
```

Works fine on Python 2.6 through 3.6:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" issue.py
True
```

But is no longer setting the `self.option` properly in 3.7.

```
"C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" issue.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "issue.py", line 28, in <module>
    loaded = pickle.load(open(pickle_file, 'rb'))
  File "issue.py", line 21, in extend
    self.append(item)
  File "issue.py", line 16, in append
    obj = self.option(obj)
AttributeError: 'MyList' object has no attribute 'option'
```

If I were to remove the `extend` function, it works as expected though.

I have tried adding `__setstate__` as well, but it is not called before `extend` so the `option` is still undefined at that point.

I do have to inherit directly from `dict` and `list`, and I do need to overwrite both the `append` and `extend` function in my code. Is there a way to set `option` beforehand or another fix?  Is this change in behavior documented and the rational for it?

Thank you for your time

Comment: You can't `print()` an assertion, can you please fix that?

Comment: whoops, fixed, thanks. @MartijnPieters

Comment: It's clear that `list.extend()` is now used to restore the pickled data, before any other attributes are set. I'm looking into *why* that is and what a good workaround would be. Worst-case: detect that `options` is not yet set in `append` or `extend` and store that data for `__init__` to pick up later on.

Comment: Found the issue where this change was made: https://bugs.python.org/issue29368

Comment: @JETM: that's not quite it though. Switching from append to extend is fine, there must be *another* change that switched when `__dict__` is restored.

Comment: @JETM: ah, no, I see now what happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unpickling list objects [switched from using `list.append()` to `list.extend()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/f89fdc29937139b55dd68587759cadb8468d0190), because that can be way faster for some `list` subclasses.

However, *with that change*, the way that the unpickling code tested for list objects also changed, from

```c
if (PyList_Check(list)) {
```

to

```c
if (PyList_CheckExact(list)) {
```

It is that change that affects your code. The above test looks for a fast path, saying *if we have a list class, then use `PyList_SetSlice()` to load the data, rather than a slower path of explicitly calling either the `.extend()` or `.append()` method on the new instance*. The old version (Python 3.6 and older) accepted lists **and subclasses**, the new version only accepts `list` itself, not subclasses!

So for Python 3.6 and older, **when unpickling your custom `MyList.append()` method is not called**, purely because you subclassed `list`. In Python 3.7, when unpickling your custom `MyList.extend()` method **is** called. This is very much intentional, subclasses *should* be allowed to provide a custom `.extend()` method that gets to be called when unpickling.

And the work-around is simple. Your data is *already* wrapped when unpickling, you don't need to re-apply that wrapper. When you do not have `self.option` set, **simply skip applying it**:

```
def append(self, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        try:
            obj = self.option(obj)
        except AttributeError:
            # something's wrong, are we unpickling on Python 3.7 or newer?
            if 'option' in self.__dict__:
                # no, we are not, because 'option' has been set, this must
                # be an error in the option() call, so re-raise
                raise
            # yes, we are, just ignore this, obj is already wrapped
    super(MyList, self).append(obj)
```

This all does mean you can't rely on any instance attributes having been restored yet. If that's a big problem (you still need to consult instance state while unpickling), then you'll have to provide a different [`__reduce_ex__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce_ex__), one that doesn't return the data as an iterator in index 3 of the resulting tuple. `list().__reduce_ex__()` for protocol versions 2, 3 and 4 returns `(copyreg.__newobj__, type(self), self.__dict__, iter(self), None)`.

A custom version would have to use `(type(self), (tuple(self), self.option), None, None, None)`, for example. That does come with some additional overhead (that `tuple(self)` there will take additional memory when pickling and unpickling).

Comment: Beautiful find and fix. Thank you so much!

Comment: can you help me understand how this impacts the logging module? I get a weird error running on a 3.6 env a piece of code developed on 3.7  saying `can't pickle _thread.rlock objects` and it seems like the logging module is the issue since I do not import multiprocessing

Comment: @Yuca: This doesn't impact the logging module, nothing in logging subclasses `list`. You have a different problem altogether, but without any further context I can't help narrow it down, sorry.